# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string and Array to string conversion Error in PHP JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Am Getting notice and warning like
Notice: Array to string conversion in I:\xampp\htdocs\ss\filters.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in I:\xampp\htdocs\ss\filters.php on line 26

It is a filter script which filters data from mysql when particular checkbox is ticked. Help me to get a solution.

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");
if(!empty($_POST))
    {
         $response = array();   
    $response["product"] = array() ;
    $value = "";
        $query ="SELECT * FROM product WHERE PhoneMake="."'$value'";
        $query_params = array ( ':PhoneMake' => $_POST['PhoneMake']);


        try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}



 if($query === "false") {
   die(mysql_error());
  }
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $response["row[PhoneMake]"];                
                 $tmp = array();
        $tmp["PhoneMake"] = $row ["PhoneMake"];
        array_push ($response["product"], $tmp);
            }

    }

else
    {
?>
    <h1>Filter</h1> 
    <form action="" method="post"> 
       <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Filter by brand</div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="PhoneMake[]" value=" Samsung "> Samsung</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="PhoneMake[]" value="Apple "> Apple</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="PhoneMake[]" value="Nokia "> Nokia</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="PhoneMake[]" value="HTC "> HTC</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="PhoneMake[]" value="Motorola "> Motorola</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="PhoneMake[]" value=" Xolo">Xolo</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="PhoneMake[]" value=" OnePlus "> OnePlus</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="PhoneMake[]" value=" OnePlus "> OnePlus</label><br>
          </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 
    </form>
<?php
}

?>
```

And my Config.inc.php file is

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbname = "street";     
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

try 
{ 

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 


if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{ 
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $value = stripslashes($value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
} 


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

session_start(); 


?>
```

I am doing this JSON for Android.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to pass in the query string in `mysql_fetch_array()`. And since you are already using PDO, why not fetch the data using that?

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM product WHERE PhoneMake = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($value));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row) {
     print $row->product;
     // .. etc
}
```

Comment: What should i do for Array to string conversion Notice ?

Comment: Get rid of that code and replace it what I gave you above.

Comment: I have replaced the code as you said.. But still it showing Array to string conversion notice.

Comment: Not sure why that is. Although I would write the query like my above updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide Connection object to mysql_fetch_array